# PlacePicker for android cannot get current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-places-api

I have tried PlacePicker sample provided by Google
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places

When I run this sample application, it shows Place Picker successfully. However, it can not get current location and shows Unknown.
[image]

I sure I have created API_KEY and enabled "Google Places API for Android" in Google Developer Console.
And I have set "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission, and set values for om.google.android.geo.API_KEY.

What would be the possible reasons for this case happen?

Comment: Have you enable the GPS for you cell? I tired it and it was working fine.

Comment: @bjian I have enabled GPS. And sure GPS works as I used Google Map app to location my current location.

Comment: That's weird, cuz it works fine on my phone. Have you tried to change a device or re-clone the project? Are you in the US?

Comment: @bjian After I tried on another phone and it works fine. Maybe the first phone I used is having problem with its play service or gps service. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

After I tried on another phone and it works fine.

It seems the first phone I used is having problem with its play service or gps service.